# I only have the original files of database but no .bak file, how do I restore the database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

We were upgrading a server from SQL Server 2012 to 2014 at work and it was giving us trouble so I passed it off to someone else who, when backing up the SQL Server database, didn't create a `.bak` file. All he did was save the files from the folder Microsoft SQL Server (110, 120 and client SDK), the regular and x86 version.

My question is there any way I can just transfer the contents of these files to their respective folders on my new server or is this just completely lost?

Thanks.

Comment: Amazing,if you are having mdf,ldf files,you can go ahead with attach,detach option

Comment: @TheGameiswar can you explain where to find those files or point me in a direction on how to use them please?